# Count() arithmetic in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
comments (
  id        int
  comment   int
)

commentvotes (
  commentid int
  positive  bool
)
```

Where commentvotes.positive determines whether a vote was an upvote or a downvote.

Is there any way, with a single query, that I can get all of the upvotes and downvotes, ideally in a column each? More generally, can you run two counts with different selection criteia in the same query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do stupid tricks with `SUM`:

```
SELECT commentid, SUM(positive) upvotes, SUM(NOT positive) downvotes FROM commentvotes;
```

MySQL booleans are actually just integers, 0 or 1.  Adding them up effectively counts how many times a condition is true.  So if you have:

```
commentid | positive
----------|---------
 1        |  true
 1        |  true
 1        |  false
 1        |  true
 1        |  false
```

Then `SUM(positive)` is `1+1+0+1+0` = 3.  `SUM(NOT positive)` is `0+0+1+0+1` = 2.  You can do this in other databases, too, but usually need an explicit cast.

One caveat: because MySQL has no real boolean type, your `positive` column is actually `TINYINT(1)`, and could contain any number that fits in a byte, which will throw off `SUM(positive)`.  You can use `SUM(NOT NOT positive)`, or a cast, or use a database that doesn't lie to you quite so much.  ;)

If this is all too arcane for you (rightfully so), the easy way out is to denormalize a bit and give `comments` `upvotes` and `downvotes` columns.  Or you could use a subquery for upvotes and another for downvotes, but in my experience MySQL is particularly bad with grouping operations and subqueries.

Comment: Might also want to explain why `not positive` is -1. :)

Comment: Thanks for that, ideal. Changing the table would be a bit of a pain because there's a bit more to it than I've expressed, but moot because sum works well. As a sidenote, when you say that mysql has trouble with subqueries, in what way? Just a lack of available features, or a matter of performance? I've never really considered any other databases, because there never seemed to be a significant difference between them.

Comment: I don't believe MySQL can always use indexes within subqueries, so joins and `GROUP BY` and simple comparisons are frequently much slower than they'd be otherwise.  I recently migrated to PostgreSQL and I'm quite happy with it; open source, well supported, far fewer gotchas, and some cool advanced features.  Heavily biased comparison: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Why_PostgreSQL_Instead_of_MySQL_2009